# Communication between Clojure services

Tags: clojure, microservices

I need to put a Clojure service to communicate with another through HTTP calls, in java we can do something like that using RestTemplate like this:

```
             ResponseEntity<Product[]> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(
                    "http://localhost:8001/products/store/all", Product[].class);
```

What would be the similar way in Clojure to do the same job with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) and any JSON parser like [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire):

```clj
(ns example
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client]
            [cheshire.core :as :json]))

(def products
   (-> (client/get "http://localhost:8001/products/store/all") 
       (json/parse-string true)))
```

Comment: minor observation: probably you want this to be a function instead, but I agree with the recommendation otherwise (including the libraries)

Comment: If cheshire is on the classpath, clj-http can do the json-SerDe even for you.  The above example lacks most likely a `:body` after the `get`.